# Adding action in second Odata Controller throws Path template Error

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api2

While working on Odata and Web API, I came across the following scenario:

1. when there is only one controller in the We API having unbound
   action, service works fine.
2. When another controller is added with unbound action, it throws error 'path template 'ActionName' on the action 'ActionName' in controller 'ControllerName' is not a valid OData path template. Resource not found for the segment 'TestComponent'. Please click on the link below to see the error.

[***path template 'TestComponent' on the action 'TestComponent' in controller 'Test' is not a valid OData path template. Resource not found for the segment 'TestComponent'.***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1sA1.png)

The code used to route the request:

```
ODataConventionModelBuilder testSetupBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        testSetupBuilder.Action("TestAction").Parameter<string>("actionParameter");

        config.MapODataServiceRoute(
           "ODataRouteTestSetUp",
           "odata/testsetup",
           testSetupBuilder.GetEdmModel(),
           new DefaultODataBatchHandler(server)
           );
```

Comment: See if this answer helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27226116/2069745