# Is it possible to expose multiple Odata v4 endpoints in Asp.Net WebApi project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata, odata-v4

The title explains the requirement.
Is it possible to expose multiple endpoints in single project?

Something like:

- http://localhost:8000/svc1/$metadata
- http://localhost:8000/svc2/$metadata
- http://localhost:8000/svc3/$metadata

Because I need to divide functionality into multiple components.
Can anyone help me?

**UPDATE**

Currently I'm using below code to create and expose Odata service.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
   HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
   ConfigureRoute(config);
   ConfigureGlobalFilters(config);

   HttpServer server = new HttpServer();
   ODataBatchHandler batchHandler = new DefaultODataBatchHandler(server);
   config.MapODataServiceRoute("Odata", "Odata", GenerateEdmModel(), batchHandler);


   ...

   config.EnsureInitialized();
}

private IEdmModel GenerateEdmModel()
{
   ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
   builder.Namespace = "ServiceA";
   builder.ContainerName = "DefaultContainer";

   builder.EntitySet<Permission>("ApplicationPermissions");

   return builder.GetEdmModel();
}
```

I would like to expose separate services for each component (under different namespaces?).

Comment: yes, you should be able to set up multiple routes, one for each OData endpoint. However, without knowing how you've implemented your service (are you using `IAppBuilder` etc) it's hard to answer directly.

Comment: @Brad, Thanks for your input. Now I have updated the question, perhaps you can answer now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line should be the one you care about:

```
config.MapODataServiceRoute("Odata", "Odata", GenerateEdmModel(), batchHandler);
```

The second string parameter is the `routePrefix`, which means currently you're probably hitting http://yourhost.com/Odata/$metadata. If you simply create another mapping with a *different* prefix value (e.g. `Odata2`) you'd be able to make calls against http://yourhost.com/Odata/$metadata AND http://yourhost.com/Odata2/$metadata. You'll probably want to give them both a unique routeName as well though (the first string parameter), and you'll probably want to provide a different model as well so the two services will actually be different :).

Comment: This worked, but got an exception. Solution is available here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27156638/adding-a-new-odata-controller-fails-existing-controller